# How do I SELECT all (table, column) referencing the same column as foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, plpgsql, information-schema

(TL;DR at the end)

I am working on merging 2 well sized postgres databases.
As there are ID conflicts and many foreign keys I would have enjoyed that  `UPDATE foo SET bar_id = bar_id + 100000 CASCADE`  was a thing in SQL so it magically update everything accordingly. Unfortunately, it's not.

So I want to use a LOOP structure (see below) that will simply edit the references everywhere.
I want a select query the return all table_name, column_name that references the column I want.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    rec record;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN 
    (SELECT table_name, column_name FROM /*??*/ WHERE /*??*/)   -- <<< This line    
    LOOP  
    EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I SET %s = %s + 100000 ;',  
        rec.table_name,rec.column_name,rec.column_name); 
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I know already how to get all tables (+column_name) having a specific column_name that I use when the foreign key column share the name with the column it references. Or even if it's a list of column_name I know:

```
SELECT col.table_name, col.column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns col 
        right join
        information_schema.tables tab 
        ON col.table_name = tab.table_name 
        WHERE column_name = 'foo_id' 
        --  IN ('FOO_ID','BAR_FOO_ID') | or : like '%foo_id' | both works well most of the time
        and tab.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

But...
I am now with a table PLACES with the `place_id` column being referenced on at least 60 different constraints (matching `LIKE '%place_id'`). *Then there is columns referencing the place id named otherwise* like 'foo_currentplace','foo_storageroom', 'foo_lastrecomposition_place', 'operating_theatre' and so on. In the other hand, there is columns referring 'placetype_id' from placetype table which are `LIKE '%place%'`  and I do NOT want to change the placetype_id, so we can not guess which column is to include or not only from their name.

I know there is the `information_schema.table_constraints` table, but it does NOT tell the referenced column.
If we can have the definition from the constraint name, it could be possible to match :
`ILIKE format('%%REFERENCES %s(%s)%%',table_name,column_name)`
but the definition isn't part of the `table_constraints` table either.

(For those wondering, I'm working on Hospital databases related to sterilization services.)

**WHAT I WANT / TL;DR**

I need a SELECT query (or a function definition ) returning all column of the whole database `(schema_name,table_name,column_name)` or `(table_name,column_name)` having a foreign key constraint referencing a specified column (parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I have done it :-)
The following query returns every column in database referencing `FOO_TABLE.foo_column` as foreign key:

```
SELECT 
fk.table_schema as schema, --optional in my case, I only use public
fk.table_name as table,
substring(fk.constraint_def, 14, position(')' in constraint_def)-14) as column
FROM
    (SELECT tc.*,
     pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid) as constraint_def
     --,c.oid 
     from pg_constraint c
     left join information_schema.table_constraints tc
     on c.conname = tc.constraint_name
     where tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY')
     as fk    
WHERE constraint_def ILIKE format('%%REFERENCES %s(%s)%%',
                                 'FOO_TABLE','foo_column')  
ORDER BY table_schema,table_name,3;
```

[Test it there](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4dd8b9dbe59b560b8b71c1fe29738a75)

I've found `information_schema.table_constraints` gets most of the information from `pg_constraint` which includes internal reference `OID`, and there is a built-in function `pg_get_constraintdef()` returning the definition of constraint object from it's `OID`.
Then, some substring of the definition is enough to extract the `column_name` AND
filter over the referenced column with the `(I)LIKE` filter I've prepared in my question.

----------------- OTHER ANSWER ------------------

Another acceptable query I've built from improving @Abelisto suggestion :

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
FROM (SELECT table_name, SUBSTR(column_name, 2, LENGTH(column_name)-2) as column_name,
             referenced_table,SUBSTR(referenced_column, 2, LENGTH(referenced_column)-2) as referenced_column
      FROM(select
             conrelid::regclass::text as table_name,
            (select array_agg(attname) from pg_attribute where conrelid = attrelid and attnum = any(conkey))::text as column_name,
             confrelid::regclass::text as referenced_table,
            (select array_agg(attname) from pg_attribute where confrelid = attrelid and attnum = any(confkey))::text as referenced_column
             from pg_constraint where contype = 'f' 
             ) b ) a
WHERE (referenced_table, referenced_column) = ('FOO_TABLE','foo_column');
```

[Test it there](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b0ce516a48d2c5465b3f7881c0d5830e)

I don't think performances really matters there, so one should pick regarding what are the side needs. I think my first solution have the advantage to get the constraint definition if you want to alter it (say, for exemple, add a `ON UPDATE CASCADE` clause), yet the second seems more "compact" for this very purpose of just returning the table.column.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff : From this, I can either cluster uptdate or altering the constraints to set `ON UPDATE CASCADE` on all of them with pl/pgsql. Both would works, but I'll stick to my clustering update method because I don't want to do another function that will undo the 1st just to remove the ON UPDATE CASCADE clause afterward.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2167a1a47b971ca61ff9d5ec7b0b4282

Answer (score -1):

This is perhaps too long for a comment.

Postgres definitely supports cascading update constraints (see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)).  However, this is part of the *definition* of the constraint, not the `update` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE foo 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_foo_bar_id FOREIGN KEY (bar_id) REFERENCES bar(bar_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;
----^ this is the important part
```

Note:  You will need to redefine all your foreign key constraints to make them cascading update constraints.

And, as an editorial comment, I generally avoid cascading update foreign key constraints (because I don't like the idea of primary keys changing values).  However, this is definitely a place where they are useful.

Then if you change `bar.bar_id`, the change will be reflected in `foo`.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f2c1e1d0f3fb5a4ae10f859983c43e00) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Well yes, the redefinition of constraint can be a good workaround instead of cluster updates, BUT that does not change the problem : I have no reliable and fast way to *identify* or *loop over* all column (or constrainst name) being foreign key referencing `bar_id`. I mean, without manually scrolling through and hundred of tables and thousands of constraints definition in order to do so.

Comment: @MartialP . . . Ironically, you can attempt the update and see what errors you get.

Comment: Well, do you know how can I make a loop trying the same update again and again but adding an `ON UPDATE CASCADE` clause to the violated constraint mentionned in the error at every iteration ? :-)

Comment: @MartialP. . .  The idea would be that one table would fail and you would fix that with a cascading update.  Then the next would fail . . . and so on.

Comment: I understood right, (And yes I laughed) . I'm just a big fan of not being a computer myself. If I can `repeat` edit the definitions of the violated constraints  `until`  the update no longer rise an error, I consider there must be a way to tell it to my computer to do it for me, escpecially since I heard a theory telling computers were litterally made for doing stuff like that. My answer was just as much ironical as yours.

Comment: @MartialP . . . Sometimes the simplest way to solve problems is hacking away, one by one.  Sometimes, it is better to figure out everything in advance, and do it in one fell swoop.